# "PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmptnjzak66'" when installing pyqt5 with pip3 in pypy3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pyqt5

I'm trying to install pyqt5 in pypy3, but whenever I try, I keep getting this error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmptnjzak66'".
```

I tried doing it in Command Prompt as Administrator and using the --user flag in pip, but that didn't work.

FULL ERROR:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\pypy\pypy3.7-v7.3.4-win64\pypy3.exe' 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\pypy\pypy3.7-v7.3.4-win64\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb7oo_ix0'
     cwd: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9uip9ajh\pyqt5_2071a330a78c4514821de14c8db3af03
Complete output (40 lines):
Querying qmake about your Qt installation...
C:\Qt\6.0.3\mingw81_64\bin\qmake.exe -query
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\pypy\pypy3.7-v7.3.4-win64\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 126, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
    hook = backend.prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\pypy\pypy3.7-v7.3.4-win64\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 280, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\pypy\pypy3.7-v7.3.4-win64\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 263, in main
    json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\pypy\pypy3.7-v7.3.4-win64\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 131, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
    config_settings)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\pypy\pypy3.7-v7.3.4-win64\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 159, in _get_wheel_metadata_from_wheel
    whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-yw5ohkpr\overlay\site-packages\sipbuild\api.py", line 51, in build_wheel
    project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('pep517')
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-yw5ohkpr\overlay\site-packages\sipbuild\abstract_project.py", line 83, in bootstrap
    project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-yw5ohkpr\overlay\site-packages\sipbuild\project.py", line 500, in setup
    self.update(tool)
  File "project.py", line 162, in update
sipbuild.exceptions.UserException
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\pypy\pypy3.7-v7.3.4-win64\lib-python\3\weakref.py", line 681, in _exitfunc
    f()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\pypy\pypy3.7-v7.3.4-win64\lib-python\3\weakref.py", line 605, in __call__
    return info.func(*info.args, **(info.kwargs or {}))
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\pypy\pypy3.7-v7.3.4-win64\lib-python\3\tempfile.py", line 797, in _cleanup
    _shutil.rmtree(name)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\pypy\pypy3.7-v7.3.4-win64\lib-python\3\shutil.py", line 516, in rmtree
    return _rmtree_unsafe(path, onerror)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\pypy\pypy3.7-v7.3.4-win64\lib-python\3\shutil.py", line 404, in _rmtree_unsafe
    onerror(os.rmdir, path, sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\pypy\pypy3.7-v7.3.4-win64\lib-python\3\shutil.py", line 402, in _rmtree_unsafe
    os.rmdir(path)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp794te2tp'
```

**COMMAND I'M USING:**
`pypy3 -m pip install --user pyqt5`